# Monitoring Eclipse performance: what is Eclipse doing?

Tags: performance, eclipse, monitoring

Lately I have been experiencing Eclipse Galileo (3.5) slowing down under Java 1.5b12 OR Java 1.6b10, every 10 to 15 minutes for about 30 seconds, it hits a 90-95% CPU load. The progress view shows nothing, however.

I'm suspecting a plugin is causing issues, but what I'd need is some tool or plugin to monitor Eclipse for what it is doing during those spikes.

Does such a plugin or tool exist?

---

Edit #1: added details about Eclipse version and Java version (d'uh, sorry)

Comment: Eclipse is the Borg of the IDE world - it assimilates all projects and adds their distinctiveness to its collective. It's beginning to achieve consciousness.

Comment: Yeah I almost feel like watching my network performance to make sure my Eclipse isn't starting to work together with other Eclipses to take over the world...

Comment: What version of eclipse/JDK are you using?

Comment: You did see the two links for the "right eclipse.ini", right? I will edit my answer to make them more visible though.

Comment: Note: the exact version (build) of JDK6 used to launched eclipse  is important. I recommend the latest one (6b16). More details in the "eclipse.ini 3.5" link mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Glad this new setup works for you. I believe this is the *combination* of the JDK *and* the `eclipse.ini` settings that make eclipse runs so well (or at least much better).

Comment: sounds like a garbage collection piling up... glad the latest JDK fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the right eclipse.ini, you can then monitor an eclipse session with JConsole.

- **[eclipse.ini for 3.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/144349#144349)**
- **[eclipse.ini for 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590)**

I had the same issue with old eclipse3.4 or 3.4.1 installation. In both cases, switching to eclipse3.5 with the latest JDK solved the problem.

Comment: info on what the "right eclipse.ini" is would be appreciated, sounds great.

Comment: ahh...now I get it, the links on the numbers are links to eclipse.ini's. Thought they were links to the Eclipse pages. :D

Comment: Thanks, I will be trying this and see if it helps (I also never tried build 1.6b16 yet).

Comment: Updating to 1.6b16 really helped - the slowdowns went away, thanks!

Comment: FYI: jvisualvm can watch an eclipse without any tinkering.  Does your ini file expose additional information relevant for surveillance?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: yes: `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` registers the JVM instrumentation MBeans and publishes the RMI connector via a private interface to allow JMX client applications to monitor a local Java platform, that is, a JVM running on the same machine. See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/agent.html

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516142/does-java-6-open-a-default-port-for-jmx-remote-connections