# How to connect to a local JMX server by knowing the process id?

Tags: java, service, process, jmx

The motivation behind this is to manage local java services, using JMX, without something more heavyweight like the java service Wrapper.

Each service is started with `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` which means that "The JVM is configured to work as a local (same-machine-only) JMX server." (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516142/does-java-6-open-a-default-port-for-jmx-remote-connections) for a good explaination).

I tried the [Attach API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/index.html), but decided against it since it is not bundled with Java SE6 and and integrating it with maven was not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Tim Büthe

If `ConnectorAddressLink.importFrom` returns null, try loading management-agent.jar into VM.

For example with something like function `startManagementAgent` from https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/test/sun/management/jmxremote/bootstrap/TestManager.java

```
private static void startManagementAgent(String pid) throws IOException {
    /*
     * JAR file normally in ${java.home}/jre/lib but may be in ${java.home}/lib
     * with development/non-images builds
     */
    String home = System.getProperty("java.home");
    String agent = home + File.separator + "jre" + File.separator + "lib"
            + File.separator + "management-agent.jar";
    File f = new File(agent);
    if (!f.exists()) {
        agent = home + File.separator + "lib" + File.separator +
            "management-agent.jar";
        f = new File(agent);
        if (!f.exists()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("management-agent.jar missing");
        }
    }
    agent = f.getCanonicalPath();

    System.out.println("Loading " + agent + " into target VM ...");

    try {
        VirtualMachine.attach(pid).loadAgent(agent);
    } catch (Exception x) {
        throw new IOException(x.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm posting the question to share the solution since I haven't seen it here (Q&A).
The key here is to use `ConnectorAddressLink.importFrom(pid)` to get the address.

```
public static MBeanServerConnection getLocalMBeanServerConnectionStatic(int pid) {
    try {
        String address = ConnectorAddressLink.importFrom(pid);
        JMXServiceURL jmxUrl = new JMXServiceURL(address);
        return JMXConnectorFactory.connect(jmxUrl).getMBeanServerConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Of course you still have to implement a good connection handling");
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work sometimes, but sometimes `ConnectorAddressLink.importFrom` returns `null`

Comment: ConnectorAddressLink is a sun class which may be changed or removed in the future.