# What is the default port for JMX in ActiveMQ?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, jmx

I am using ActiveMQ 5.3.2 and 5.6.0.
In ActiveMQ 5.3.2, the default settings for JMX is

```
SUNJMX="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
```

In ActiveMQ 5.6.0, the default settings for JMX is

```
ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
```

So, these settings have no port definition. Could you tell me ActiveMQ is really starting JMX connection with these settings? If so, what is the default port to connect as I cannot connect to 1099. If port is randomly selected, how to find the port which ActiveMQ is using?

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516142/does-java-6-open-a-default-port-for-jmx-remote-connections as the JMX options relate to the JVM and are not ActiveMQ specific.

Answer (score 10):

Default port is 1099. This can be override by passing jmx parameters as argument to activeMQ in activeMQ start script(activemq.bat or .sh file) . Use property

***Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port*** for setting JMX port

Comment: Even though the start command has the _-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote_ parameter, I suppose you have to assure that the broker config has the flag _useJmx="true"_. Am I right ?

Answer (score 1):

if you run ActiveMQ Broker in a Spring Boot, this is a simple way to configure the JMX port to the value 11099:

```
    BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();

    broker.getManagementContext().setConnectorPort(11099);
    broker.getSystemUsage().getStoreUsage().setLimit(100_000_000L);
    broker.getSystemUsage().getTempUsage().setLimit(100_000_000L);

    TransportConnector connector = new TransportConnector();
    connector.setUri(new URI("tcp://localhost:61616?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=3000000&wireFormat.maxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=1000000"));

    broker.addConnector(connector);
    broker.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

By default it doesn't appear to bind to a "default activemq jmx port" however you can modify the activemq file (or environment variables to add one).  JMX if you don't specify a port doesn't open one by [expicitly stating one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10368260/32453).

For instance uncomment [this line](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/assembly/src/release/bin/env#L69) (or an equivalent in the activemq file for older versions)

```
 # ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=11099 "
```

So I guess you could think of that as the "default if you uncomment its config line".

Also when you issue a "stop" command and it doesn't pass a `--jmxurl` (default is port 11099 in the activemq version I run) it does default to attempting to contact `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi` even though the default config isn't listening on that port without modifying configs first.  Weird.