# Is there a JMX Service URL for local (non-TCP) connections?

Tags: java, jmx

I am attempting to use collectd to connect to a JVM process running on the same machine.  The [GenericJMX collectd plugin](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:GenericJMX) is configured via a ServiceURL which is all well and good if the JVM has remote JMX access enabled.  However, is it possible to do this *without* remote JMX access enabled?

[This detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516142/does-java-6-open-a-default-port-for-jmx-remote-connections/6985565#6985565) explains that (since Java 6) even JVMs *not* started with `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` still expose JMX access via "memory-mapped files found in `/tmp/hsperfdata_[user]`".  That's how JConsole access works.  But can I get collectd to use this connection method?  Is there such as thing as a "local" JMX Service URL?  Or do I have to enable an RMI registry port (`-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=[rmiregistryport]`) for this to work at all?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at my [jmxlocal](https://github.com/nickman/jmxlocal) GitHub. It provides JMX remoting implementations to transparently connect to in-vm MBeanServers and JVMs on the same host.

Examples:

- Connect to the default in-vm MBeanServer: **service:jmx:local:///**
- Connect to a different in-vm MBeanServer using the domain: **service:jmx:local:///jboss**
- Connect to a local JVM by pid: **service:jmx:attach://23474**
- Connect to a local JVM by display name regex: **service:jmx:attach:///[GroovyStarter.*]**